# javascript format number 2 places then 3 for 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery plugin progress meter that animates and has a callback function where I animate the text value up to the meter value.

https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

The callback value is in the format of 0.12798798 etc which I format to give 12%.

My problem is if the value is 100% my code returns 00%

```
$('#circle').circleProgress({
    startAngle: 90,
    size: 240,
    thickness: 22,
    fill: { gradient: [['#0681c4', .5], ['#4ac5f8', .5]], gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4 }
}).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
    $(this).find('strong').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2)+'%');
});
```

I am sure there is a much better approach.

Comment: Great thanks, much better. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify as follows:

```
(stepValue*100).toFixed(0) + '%'
```

Comment: This doesn't include the % or the type casting.

Comment: This is simply meant to shorten `String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2)`.  I've now added `%`, but I'm sure the OP knew to do that already.

Comment: Also, type-casting isn't needed in this situation.  `toFixed()` automatically returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should round to the nearest integer:

```
Math.round(0.12798798*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

toFixed(2) gives you two decimal places...  use 0 and you don't need the substr

```
 $(this).find('strong').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(0))+'%');
```